# Blender 2.83 : Edge Bevel not round

Tags: bevel

I'm new to Blender. I'm using Blender 2.83 and I saw in some youtube tutorials that you can  make a cube's edge round using bevel (edit mode), however I wasn't able to replicate it.

Here is what I did:

1. go to edit mode
2. select edge
3. ctrl+B and mouse wheel up to create more segments

The final result created a flat cut not a curved one. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

uncheck "custom profile" (just below "grid fill / cutoff")

(or create a round custom profile ;))

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who can't find the popup menu, when using the bevel, use mouse wheel up or down to round the edges more or less.

Comment: if you can't find the popup, make sure that 'adjust last operation' is checked in the 'view' menu.